# Apache Geode Configuration

Tags: configuration, gemfire, geode

I had a problem trying to get Apache Geode (v1.0.0-incubating.M2) running on Linux.

The problem was: while I was trying to run `gfsh start server --name=server1` example command from the documentation it gave me the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" com.gemstone.gemfire.InternalGemFireError: Cannot resolve local host name to an IP address`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you need to have your hostname (given by output of `hostname` command) be present in `/etc/hosts` file.

In my case, `hostname` gives an alias as an output (let's say `my_alias`), so I solved the problem by adding `my_ip my_full_domain my_alias` line to `/etc/hosts`.